# Is it possible to customize how image is loaded while still using `img.loading` attribute?

Tags: html

For images in my webpage, instead of just specifying some image url, I need to load the image data from my own API as a binary data, and then set the `src` as `data/jpeg;base64,....`. i.e, I probably need a customized function to load the image content.

However I also want to do the loading lazily. So the ways I can think of are:

1. set `src` as empty initially, and listen to various mouse events myself or use `Intersection Observer API` to trigger my customized function to actually load and set `src`
2. find some way to override image's loading function? so that I could still use the [native lazy loading](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_loading.asp) provided by chrome?

Is option 2 possible? If so, how to override?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just rewrite your own api to serve the image correctly ?

Comment: the image url is a cloud storage url that is out of my control, now I have to use their authenticated API to retrieve binary and serve myself.

Comment: then yes to have to manually load it with javascript, depending on how their authorization works you can also just set the src attribute with javascript once you have access to it (like if the API can use cookies or url parameters for authentication)